If I apply the 3D graphics acceleration on a virtual PC, then I can not get the correct Gazebo display with robot, only an empty world. Why?
If I apply the 3D graphic acceleration, then I can start Gazebo correctly with a robot or object displayed in the world. If I do not apply the 3D graphics acceleration, then I can use a command like gz sim xxx.sdf to start the gazebo correctly.
However, when I use an SDF file that includes an STL file which is quite a big 3D file about 6 MB, then I get the wrong message that I posted below.
How can I solve this issue?

My host PC is Windows 10, and use VMWare Player.
The virtual PC OS is Ubuntu 22.04 desktop, with ROS2 Humble and Gazebo Harmonic installed.

Error message:
VMware: No 3D enabled (0, Success).
libEGL warning: egl: failed to create dri2 screen
VMware: No 3D enabled (0, Success).
libEGL warning: egl: failed to create dri2 screen

